# How to get a boss character to fire at all directions at once

Tags: sprite-kit, game-physics

I'm new to SpriteKit game development. I'm trying give a boss character the ability to cast fireballs in multiple directions (16 fireballs all at once, 360 degree/16 = 22.5 degree apart).
I know how to get him to fire at a certain position by providing the player's current position, but how to get him to fire at 16 different angles regardless of player's position?

Thanks for any help in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, set up a loop over the angles

```
let numAngles = 16
var angle:CGFloat = 0
var angleIncr = CGFloat(2 * M_PI) / CGFloat(numAngles)
let strength:CGFloat = 50
for _ in 0..<numAngles {
    ...        
    angle += angleIncr
}
```

In the loop, convert the angle to the corresponding vector components and then create a vector

```
let dx = strength * cos (angle)
let dy = strength * sin (angle)

let vector = CGVectorMake (dx, dy)
```

and create a new fireball and apply an impulse to its physics body

```
let fireball = ...
fireball.position = player.position
fireball.zRotation = angle

// Add a physics body here

fireball.physicsBody?.appyImpulse (vector)
```

Comment: Thank you so much. It worked perfectly! Just had to tune down the strength factor to 0.2 otherwise they travel crazy fast.

Comment: You're welcome. If an answer solves your problem, you should consider accepting it by clicking on the checkmark to the left of the answer.

Comment: One more question, if i use the following code in touchesBegan to get a player movement angle(in 360 degrees), then how can i convert it to a vector and let him cast single fireball using your code? Thanks again.                    let dx = CGFloat(joypadCenter.x) - CGFloat(location.x)
   let dy = CGFloat(joypadCenter.y) - CGFloat(location.y)
   let angle = 180 + (atan2(dx, dy) * (180/3.14159))

Comment: Are you trying to shoot a single fireball in the direction that the player is facing?

Comment: The angle to shoot the fireball is `let angle = player.zRotation`. The vector is `let vector = CGVectorMake(strength*cos(angle), strength*sin(angle))`.

Comment: Unfortunately the player doesn't use zRotations. I used the above mentioned code to get an angle in 360 degrees and divide it into 8 general directions, north, northeast, northwest, south, southeast, and southwest. How can i convert my angle (in 360 degrees) to something that can be used in your code and still be able to make the player fire in the direction his facing?

Comment: Try `let angle = CGFloat(M_PI) + atan2(dy, dx)`

Comment: i tried the following, but no matter which direction the player is facing the fire ball only travels to West:      let strength :CGFloat = 5
                    let x = CGFloat(joypadCenter.x) - CGFloat(location.x)
                    let y = CGFloat(joypadCenter.y) - CGFloat(location.y)
                     let angle = CGFloat(M_PI) + atan2(y, x)
let vector = CGVectorMake(strength*cos(angle), strength*sin(angle))
                 projectileEntity.spriteComponent.node.physicsBody?.applyImpulse(vector)

Comment: The joypad is made of a rectangle of size 128,128. so the joypadCenter is at 64,64. And yes, the location is the tap point inside the joypad.

Comment: Try `var dx = location.x - joypadCenter.x`, `var dy = location.y - joypadCenter.y`, `let mag = sqrt(dx*dx+dy*dy)`, `dx /= mag`, `dy /= mag` and `let angle = atan2(strength*dy, strength*dx)`

Comment: so, after i calculated the angle then i plugged in the angle to the rest of the code, but still fires at West direction only .                    let x = cos (angle),
                    let y = sin (angle),
                    let vector = CGVectorMake (x, y),
                    projectileEntity.spriteComponent.node.physicsBody?.applyImpulse(vector)

Comment: Sorry, my previous comment contained an extra, unneeded step. You can use `dx` and `dy` directly without converting them to an angle. However, it should have worked with the extra step. I suggest you add a breakpoint after on the line that computes the vector, so you can examine the values of `dx` and `dy` or add a print statement to write the values to the console. `dx` and `dy` should change when you tap on different locations on the joypad.

Comment: So I did as you suggested, printed out the result on the console for let x = CGFloat(joypadCenter.x) - CGFloat(location.x), let y = CGFloat(joypadCenter.y) - CGFloat(location.y), and got the output -> dx:-420.499938964844 dy:48.0

Comment: It looks like the joypad and location have different coordinate systems. Are you receiving the touch event from with the joypad? If so you don't need to subtract the joypad's location from location. In other words, `dx = location.x` and `dy = location.y`.

Comment: hmm..that's strange, how can they have different coordinate systems, because the touch location is inside the joypad. anyways, i tried to use dx = location.x and dy = location.y directly and still didn't work.

Comment: I've figured it out. silly me. The fireball button is outside of the joypad, therefore using joypadCenter.position - touch.position will always return the same value no matter where the player is facing. LOL. Your code works perfectly once I ignored the touch position on fireball button. Thanks again for all your helps!

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what code you have in place. for shooting.  but ill give this a shot.  angles in spritekit are in radians and a there are 2*pi radians in a circle.  so you just need to do something like this

```
let fireballs = 16
let threeSixty = CGFloat(M_PI*2)
for i in 1...fireballs {
    let angle = (CGFloat(i) / CGFloat(fireballs)) * threeSixty
    // do something useful with your angle
}
```